# Using str.contains() does not find strings after a plus signal (+)

Tags: string, pandas, contains

I working a code to work a dataframe where one of the columns has strings like "102334+2N" or "102334+2G" or "102334+3" and so on. 
When using str.contains(), nothing is found after the plus signal (+).

This works pretty fine:

```
df.loc[df['SKU'].str.contains(r"102334", case=False), ["SKU", "DESCRIPTION"]]
```

This locates all with the "102334" plus any aditional string

```
df.loc[df['SKU'].str.contains(r"102334+", case=False), ["SKU", "DESCRIPTION"]]
```

This locates nothing:

```
df.loc[df['SKU'].str.contains(r"102334+2", case=False), ["SKU", "DESCRIPTION"]]
```

I'd appreciate any answer that help me to understand how to solve it.

Result correct for:
df.loc[df['SKU'].str.contains(r"102334", case=False), ["SKU", "DESCRIPTION"]]

[image]

Result incorrect (the last line was not expected):

df.loc[df['SKU'].str.contains(r"102334+", case=False), ["SKU", "DESCRIPTION"]]

[image]

and the last results present no item (expected 1 to 3):

df.loc[df['SKU'].str.contains(r"102334+2", case=False), ["SKU", "DESCRIPTION"]]

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example where the original data frame contains three sample rows, along with the desired output, and the actual output you are seeing?  Ideally, an example would contain copy-paste-able code that creates the data frame.

Comment: it's because you're marking those as regex strings and `+` is a reserved character in regex

Comment: wpercy, I was guessing that could be something related to plus signal as a reserved signal. However how can I bypass this in my case?

Comment: Just add a `backward slash` (\) before (+) character and enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Regex parameter it was possible to solve the issue.
Correct expression: 
df.loc[df['SKU'].str.contains(r"102334+2", case=False, regex=False), ["SKU", "DESCRIPTION", "VERSÃO","BU", "CPV_M", "CF_M"]]

Thanks, wpercy for your hint.